# Interviews Using Total Probability Theorem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

> Of all the job applicants at the Apex Company who come for a job interview ,$30$% are given the interview right away. The other $70$% are asked to wait in a waiting room. About $40$% of the time, people who are asked to wait will leave the waiting room before being given the job interview, and will not return.
>
> (i) What percent of the job applicants who come for a job interview will actually have the interview?

I am not sure about this question. Would we have to use conditional probability or Baye's Formula for this. If so, can some someone please show me?

> (ii) Given that an applicant is given an interview, what is the probability that the applicant had to wait in the waiting room?

Here is my attempt:

$P$ (given an interview right away)$*$ $P$ (had to wait in waiting room) $+$ $P$ (not given an interview right away) $*$ $P$ (did not have to wait in a waiting room)

$(0.3)*(0.7)+(0.7)*(0.3)=.42$

I suppose we would have to divide this answer by the one we got in (i).

I was reading ahead about Baye's Formula and saw this question. I am not sure about part (i) and I tried on part (ii). I was thinking that we would need part (i) to use in part (ii) to get the answer. Is there a certain way I should do this? Is there a better way that I can solve this so I can see it clearer. Can someone please show me how to do this?

Comment: (1) The probability is $0.3 + 0.7*0.6$

Comment: @user130512 Can we show this by writing out a formula similar to what I did in part (ii).

Comment: P(given an interview right away) + P(waiting room)*P(stays for waiting room given waiting room)

Comment: i think that answer for part i is 72%

Comment: and for the second part it is 7/12

Answer (score 1):

Part i)

$30$% get an interview straight away, so $0.3$

$70$% have to wait, of which only $60$% stay, $0.7 * 0.6 = 0.42$ Adding these together gives $0.72$

ie. $72$% of applicants have an interview.

Part ii)

Use Bayes $P(A|B)= \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$ where | denotes 'given'. So;

$P(Had.to.wait|Had.interview)=\frac{P(Had.interview|Had.to.wait)P(Had.to.wait)}{P(Had.interview)}=\frac{0.6*0.7}{0.72}=\frac{0.42}{0.72}=\frac{7}{12}=0.58333$